# Is there any reason to replace a failing disk in a raid10 before it has completely died?

Tags: linux, raid

My home server has four 4TB disks configured as a RAID10. I've gotten a few messages recently suggesting that I'm about to lose one of my disks:

> $ WARNING: Your hard drive is failing
> Device: /dev/sdd [SAT], 8 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors
>
> WARNING: Your hard drive is failing
> Device: /dev/sdd [SAT], 8 Offline uncorrectable sectors

mdadm shows all four disks as being active and working, so the disk is still good for the time being. Is there any reason I can't just leave /dev/sdd in place until it fails altogether?

Comment: What if another one of your drives fails without giving you a warning?

Comment: Well I have a spare ready to go, if one abruptly fails I can just switch it out. It's very unlikely that two will go out at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason is that performance will be degraded since the controller may be having to do many re-reads to get failing data.